# Dim specific monitor(s) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I work with three monitors. When I would like to read something without distractions, I maximize some non-intrusive program on the other screens. This is a repetitive process that clutters my program bar.

Simply turning off the monitor has two disadvantages:

- Turning it back on is slow
- When a monitor is turned off, any docked peripherals loose connectivity and power

Is there an application that lets dim/black out specific monitors in Windows?

Comment: I don't know of such a program, but as a workaround, why don't you set a dark grayish background image (and minimize all other applications)? I'm sure there are tools that let you change the background from a batch file, so you could create shortcuts to do that, and change it back to the original.

Comment: Another possible workaround is opening paint, filling it black and fullscreening it. It will always fullscreen on the desktop it's on (Rather than your primary monitor)

Comment: What you're suggesting is basically what I'm doing now. I open two empty windows of Sublime Text, which I position on the peripheral monitors. In each window, I start distraction-free mode (shift+11).


I figured if anyone had written something to cover this user case before, here would be a good place to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After mucking around on the internet and trying a few tools - [multiscreen blank](http://nookkin.com/software/multiscreen-blank-v2.ndoc) does this *exactly*. I *haven't* tried command line mode (and with an acceptable system for macros and some other tools I regularly use for supressing the command window that pops up,this would *literally* let you hit a key or key combo to blank the screen).

You can set it to blank out *specific* screens or *parts* of it, and least in the GUI, you quite literally just doubleclick on the screen you want to blank out.

[image]

Comment: This does just what I wanted! I appreciate you coming back to this old question.

Comment: Amusingly, someone mentioned *another* one of your questions on chat, and I went "I know this". Then found out I was completely wrong, and went and tested out various methods to do this ;p.